# Recreating this layout in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to make this layout in flutter:

[Layout](https://i.imgur.com/40w3Gbv.png)

It consists of five buttons in which the fifth button is on the middle of the other four and gives a illusion that the other buttons are not rectangles.

Is this even possible in flutter? Some guidelines would be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `Stack` widget to position the Circle button at the center.

This is an example I made:

```
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
        body: Center(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      MyButton(),
                      MyButton(),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      MyButton(),
                      MyButton(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Center(
                child: MyCircleButton(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        width: 120,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        height: 120,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              print("On click");
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  class MyCircleButton extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(60.0)),
        child: Container(
          width: 120,
          height: 120,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: InkWell(
              highlightColor: Colors.red,
              onTap: () {
                print("On circle click");
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Try reading more about Flutter layouts, here you have a lot of information : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for the help and for the documentation to read.